# Determine which line of code are using pandas.core.datetools?

Tags: python, pandas

My code gives me the following warning without any indication as to where
I use `pandas.core.datetools`. Could someone suggest how I might determine where I use this?

```
 /Users/jimmy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/compat/pandas.py:56:
 FutureWarning: The pandas.core.datetools module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. 
 Please use the pandas.tseries module instead.
 from pandas.core import datetools`
```

Comment: this is a warning. not really an error. So your code should work

Comment: Look for items which start with `datetools.` in your code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The warning originate from the line `from pandas.core import datetools`.  If you don't want to use it, simply don't import and don't use it in your code.

Comment: @Usernamenotfound There is no  line in my code that begins with `datetools.`

Comment: then just delete that line. It serves no purpose